# PyTorch: Loss remains constant

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, loss-function

I've written a code in PyTorch with my own implemented loss function `focal_loss_fixed`. But my loss value stays fixed after every epoch. Looks like weights are not being updated. Here is my code snippet:

```
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(),
                          lr=lr,
                          momentum=0.9,
                          weight_decay=0.0005)


for epoch in T(range(20)):
    net.train()
    epoch_loss = 0
    for n in range(len(x_train)//batch_size):
        (imgs, true_masks) = data_gen_small(x_train, y_train, iter_num=n, batch_size=batch_size)
        temp = []
        for tt in true_masks:
            temp.append(tt.reshape(128, 128, 1))
        true_masks = np.copy(np.array(temp))
        del temp
        imgs = np.swapaxes(imgs, 1,3)
        imgs = torch.from_numpy(imgs).float().cuda()
        true_masks = torch.from_numpy(true_masks).float().cuda()
        masks_pred = net(imgs)
        masks_probs = F.sigmoid(masks_pred)
        masks_probs_flat = masks_probs.view(-1)
        true_masks_flat = true_masks.view(-1)
        print((focal_loss_fixed(tf.convert_to_tensor(true_masks_flat.data.cpu().numpy()), tf.convert_to_tensor(masks_probs_flat.data.cpu().numpy()))))
        loss = torch.from_numpy(np.array(focal_loss_fixed(tf.convert_to_tensor(true_masks_flat.data.cpu().numpy()), tf.convert_to_tensor(masks_probs_flat.data.cpu().numpy())))).float().cuda()
        loss = Variable(loss.data, requires_grad=True)
        epoch_loss *= (n/(n+1))
        epoch_loss += loss.item()*(1/(n+1))
        print('Step: {0:.2f}% --- loss: {1:.6f}'.format(n * batch_size* 100.0 / len(x_train), epoch_loss), end='\r')
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
    print('Epoch finished ! Loss: {}'.format(epoch_loss))
```

And this is my `focal_loss_fixed' function:

```
def focal_loss_fixed(true_data, pred_data):
    gamma=2.
    alpha=.25
    eps = 1e-7
    # print(type(y_true), type(y_pred))
    pred_data = K.clip(pred_data,eps,1-eps)
    pt_1 = tf.where(tf.equal(true_data, 1), pred_data, tf.ones_like(pred_data))
    pt_0 = tf.where(tf.equal(true_data, 0), pred_data, tf.zeros_like(pred_data))
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        return sess.run(-K.sum(alpha * K.pow(1. - pt_1, gamma) * K.log(pt_1))-K.sum((1-alpha) * K.pow( pt_0, gamma) * K.log(1. - pt_0)))
```

After each epoch the loss value stays constant(`5589.60328`). What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in your heavy weight decay.

Essentially, you are not *reducing the weight by `x`*, but rather you *multiply the weights by `x`*, which means that you are instantaneously only doing very small increments, leading to a (seemingly) plateauing loss function.

More explanation on this can be found in the PyTorch discussion forum (e.g., [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-pytorch-implement-weight-decay/8436), or [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/weight-decay-implementation/1796/2)). 
Unfortunately, [the source for SGD](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/sgd.html#SGD) alone also does not tell you much about its implementation.
Simply setting it to a larger value should result in better updates. You can start by leaving it out completely, and then iteratively reducing it (from `1.0`), until you get more decent results.

Comment: [dennlinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3607203/dennlinger) how do I modify `weight decay` in this code? I'm new to PyTorch and don't have much idea.

Comment: @tahsin314 The weight decay is in the optimizer variable (SGD). Make it even smaller or try not using it.

Comment: In contrast, I think it is *too small*, since it does not work the way you seem to think it does. But as @akshayk07 pointed out, simply reove the part all the way to the top in your code, where you set `weight_decay=0.0005`), and check if you see progress then.

Comment: @dennlinger but you mentioned in your answer 'heavy weight decay'.

Comment: I reduced `weight decay` and then removed it. Still, there is no change in my loss. There might be something wrong with backprop in my code I guess.

Answer (score 1):

When computing the loss you call `focal_loss_fixed()` which uses TensorFlow to compute the loss value. `focal_loss_fixed()` creates a graph and runs it in a session to get the value, and by this point PyTorch has no idea of the sequence of operations that led to the loss because they were computed by the TensorFlow backend. It is likely then, that all PyTorch sees in `loss` is a constant, as if you had written

```
loss = 3
```

So the gradient will be zero, and the parameters will never be updated. I suggest you rewrite your loss function using PyTorch operations so that the gradient with respect to its inputs can be computed.